# Empty, isset, and !=""

Tags: php

Might be a stupid question but I cant seem to find a straight answer.

Is `$id != ""` the same as `!empty($id)`?

Also is it correct to use `if(isset($id) && !empty($id))` to determine if a variable is set and is not empty/null?

Comment: http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Humm: in a nutshell,

`if($var)` means, that if `$var` is or has a value of **TRUE**,

on the opposite hand, `if(!$var)` means, if `$var` has a value of **FALSE**

`if(empty($var))` and `if(!empty($var))` similarly try to check if `$var` has any value at all, or are they empty.

```
$var = ''; // false 
$var = '1' // true
$var; // empty
$var = '1' // not empty
```

For more, head on to the PHP [**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Some examples include :

```
<?php
var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) 1);         // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) -2);        // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) "foo");     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) 2.3e5);     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array(12)); // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array());   // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

No.  `empty()` covers many other conditions besides an empty string.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php  From the documentation:

- `""` (an empty string)
- `0` (0 as an integer)
- `0.0` (0 as a float)
- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (an empty array)
- `$var;` (a variable declared, but without a value)

Also, if you want to tell if a variable "empty", then just `empty()` is needed.  No need for `isset()` as well.

Comment: +1 for adding code tags around each and every condition.

Comment: +1 for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

`empty` will just return true for undefined variables, so there's no need to double check it.

Just use `if ( ! empty($id) )`

Comment: i read that empty already performs the isset?

Comment: @Alex - Exactly. So there's no need for you to check it again. [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Answer (score 1):

> Is $id != "" the same as !empty($id)?

No, `empty` tests for all forms of empty. So it will also trigger on `0` or `null`. Comparing with the empty string using `!=` will perform a comparison based on the string conversion of `$id`.

> Also is it correct to use if(isset($id) && !empty($id)) to determine if a variable is set and is not empty/null?

Not really, this condition just tests whether `$id` is set yet does not contain an empty string, or the string `"0"`, or an integer/float `0` value, or anything that would convert to integer `0` such as boolean `false`.

There's a pretty exhaustive list [over on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/empty) of which values are considered `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, no `$id != ""` is not the same as `!empty($id)`. The difference is that if $id is not set then the first example will throw a notice that you're using an undefined variable and the second one wont.

Secondly, it is correct if you use both isset() and empty() but it's redundant since empty will not throw a notice if the variable is undefined.

Hope that was helpful to you!

Good luck and happy coding :P